# Python: use netfilterqueu and scapy, insert timestamp into orginal payload

Tags: python, iptables, scapy, netfilter

I have used iptables NFQUEUE to queue FORWARD packet,

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport XXX -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
```

and imported NetfilterQueue and scapy in Python to modify the packet payload, before re-send out.

I want to insert the system timestamp time.time() before the original packet payoad. I tried several ways, but meet the string format issue. How to write this part of code?

My code:

```
from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue
from scapy.all import *
import nfqueue
import time

def modify(packet):
    pkt=IP(packet.get_payload())

    # --> Here, I want to add time=str(time.time()),
    # --> and insert it into the beginning of original payload: 
    # --> pkt[TCP].payload =  #timestamp + #original payload

    packet.set_payload(str(pkt))
    packet.accept()

nfqueue=NetfilterQueue()
nfqueue.bind(1,modify)
try:
    nfqueue.run()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('end')
    pass
```